# Dart library import shortcuts

Tags: import, module, dart

In cases where I have to import the main file from a library in dart I have to do:

```
import 'package:<package_name>/<package_name>.dart';
```

Is there a shorthand for doing this in Dart?

Something like

```
import 'package:<package_name>';
```

Cause mentioning the package name twice seems redundant.

Comment: Not redundant. This is URI but not a path by some conventions which can be shortened.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10018 which propose better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Seems redundant but there is no way around.
The new "add import" quick fix makes this mostly a non-issue IMHO.

- DartEditor <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- WebStorm/IntelliJ <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You have to wait until analyzing is done and a hint/warning (wiggled underline) is shown.

Comment: Where is that new "quick fix"? In Dart Editor I suppose?

Comment: I use WebStorm (alt-enter) but it's an analyzer feature and also available in DartEditor (ctrl+1)